# Base code for IONIC authenticating using passport to NodeJS

Tags: node.js, authentication, ionic3

I am following Josh Morony's tutorial with the following URL.

https://www.joshmorony.com/creating-role-based-authentication-with-passport-in-ionic-2-part-1/
https://www.joshmorony.com/creating-role-based-authentication-with-passport-in-ionic-2-part-2/

The published date is not too old as it was published in Jan 2018. Unfortunately, I can't get it running. Too much errors. Can someone provide a working code for me to learn ? Some of the code is also invalid in some point which I managed to fix. But I still cannot get it running. Hope that you can help.

After I followed the tutorial below

https://www.joshmorony.com/creating-role-based-authentication-with-passport-in-ionic-2-part-2/

I ran the command ionic serve to test out the application, there I received the following error

> Typescript Error
>   Cannot find module 'ionic-native'.
>
> ...Application/Development/Cordova/josh1/client/todo->roles/src/app/app.component.ts
>   import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
>   import { StatusBar } from 'ionic-native';

I checked online and found out that I need to replace
import { StatusBar } from 'ionic-native';
with
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';

After I changed it, i received the following error,

> Property 'styleDefault' does not exist on type 'BarProp'.
>   ..Application/Development/Cordova/josh1/client/todo->roles/src/app/app.component.ts
>    statusbar.styleDefault();
>   });

The solution to it is that i need to comment out statusbar.styleDefault();

The last ionic serve command I ran shows the following error :

> Runtime Error 
>   Can't resolve all parameters for Storage: (?)
>
> Stack
>   Error: Can't resolve all parameters for Storage: (?).
>      at syntaxError (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:80025:34)
>      at CompileMetadataResolver._getDependenciesMetadata (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:95245:35)
>      at CompileMetadataResolver._getTypeMetadata (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:95080:26)
>      at CompileMetadataResolver._getInjectableMetadata (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:95060:21)
>      at CompileMetadataResolver.getProviderMetadata (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:95420:40)
>      at http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:95331:49
>      at Array.forEach ()
>      at CompileMetadataResolver._getProvidersMetadata (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:95291:19)
>      at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:94859:50)
>      at JitCompiler._loadModules (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:113952:87)

I am really lost here. No other meaningful error description provided. If you have tried the following tutorial, can you provide some assistance ?

Comment: Your question is too broad and you provided none of the errors you got. Please reformulate.

Comment: added more information and error as requested. Really hope someone can assist.